# How to always show keyboard in pageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I want to always display keyboard in all views in pageviewcontroller.
All views have uitextfield and I coded becomefirstresponder in viewdidload so the keyboard appears.
But problem is that when i set new viewcontroller or swipe in pageviewcontroller the keyboard disappears and re-appears.

Can I always show keyboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go simple.. set invisible textfield (means hidden one)! Set that as a first responder basically, this text field should be in base view controller means out of page view. as soon as you swipe the page shift responder to the required text field. hence it will not disappear and appear on page shift.

Comment: I didn't try yet, but i think it will work, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have just implemented this solution, and even though it requires some extra ninja hacking, you can get it to work properly!

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` resigns as first responder on any tap/swipe gesture. You need to handle it in your scrollview delegate method when you detect the scroll ended and then set the current page view controller's `UITextField` as first responder.

Comment: How to access the `scrollView` of a `pageController`?